# What is aviation meta for?

Tags: support

When I started my account on aviation stack exchange I was already signed up for aviation meta, but what questions do I ask on this website and what is it for?

Comment: See: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Is there anything you're wondering that *isn't* covered [in the manual^W help center](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta is for questions or discussion about the Aviation SE site itself. Questions can be about what is on topic, how things work on the site, or possible improvement, etc. All SE sites have a meta (or at least all the ones I use). I presume the reason that the Aviation SE *automatically* signs you up for meta is because the site is still in beta.

Comment: All sites have a meta child site and there isn't an additional signup for child meta sites, they are the same accounts as the main site.  The only exception to that is the main meta MSE, which is not a child meta, but its own main site with no child meta.

Comment: And automatic sign up has nothing to do with Beta.  All of the sites (other than SO) automatically sign you up for their meta when  you join.

Comment: @Lnafziger Aviation meta was the only one that came up automatically. I have about 6 orher SE forums I'm on. But no meta. I had a meta question for one of the others (linguistics I think) and had to go sign up for it separately. I thought it was kind of odd that aviation was different, but that's the only one that's in beta. I might have done something different when I signed up for aviation SE; I don't know.

Comment: Odd, I'm on a few different ones as well, and they all have Meta sites (although they only show up when I'm on that site).  TeX isn't beta and I have it there but never signed up for it.  Poker as well, but that's beta.